# Nutch crawler: Configure to accept only pages in English

Tags: configuration-files, nutch

How can I configure the *Nutch crawler* to crawl **only English** pages?

This is what I set in `nutch-site.xml`, but it does not work:

```xml
<property>
    <name>http.accept.language</name>
    <value>en-us,en-gb,en;q=0.7,*;q=0.3</value>
    <description>Value of the "Accept-Language" request header field. This allows selecting non-English language as default one to retrieve. It is a useful setting for search engines build for certain national group.
    </description>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you set: `<value>en-us,en-gb,en;q=0.7,*;q=0.3</value>` means that it prefers English but other languages (*) still there. For crawling only English pages, you should set value as below:

```
<value>en-us,en-gb,en</value>
```

To make sure, change the value in nutch-default.xml as well.

Hope this helps

-Le Quoc Do