# Nutch crawler : only need English pages

Tags: regex, web-crawler, nutch

I tried the solution suggested in - [Nutch crawler: accept only english pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422064/nutch-crawler-accept-only-english-pages) i.e adding below property to nutch-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>http.accept.language</name>
   <value>en-us,en-gb,en</value>
   <description>Value of the "Accept-Language" request header field.
   This allows selecting non-English language as default one to retrieve.
   It is a useful setting for search engines build for certain national group.
   </description>
</property>
```

I am still getting spanish url. For example - [www.google.com/es-us/asdfghjk](http://www.google.com/es-us/asdfghjk) .

Any suggestions to fix nutch-site.xml or regex-urlfilters.txt (any regex suggestion to block es-us is also very appreciated).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The property `http.accept.language` sets the HTTP header "Accept-Language" used for HTTP [content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation). In a web browser the "Accept-Language" is filled based on the browser configuration, the operating system language or the [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)). However, the URL explicitly requests a Spanish page and the server (google.com) simply ignores the conflicting "Accept-Language" header.

There is no bullet-proof solution to get only English content:

- Nutch provides a plugin "language-identifier" able to detect the content language of a page
- you could build a [focused crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focused_crawler) (cf. [this paper](https://geo-bigdata.github.io/2015/papers/S08208.pdf)) based on the simple heuristic not to follow links only from English pages
- ev. supported by regular expressions matching URLs:

  - `/en(?:-[A-Z]{2})?/` : should follow the link anyway (also if source page isn't in English)
  - `/(?:es|de|fr|...)(?:-[A-Z]{2})?/` : ignore link

In case, the crawl covers only a few sites: use the regex URL filters where possible, otherwise filter by the identified language while indexing or when querying the index.